# aspose.words putting parentheses around negative numbers

Tags: .net, mailmerge, aspose

I have a little problem with numbers in word documents. I need to merge data into a table with Aspose.Words, this part works fine. Only I need to put parentheses around negative numbers (and multiply by -1).

I've been searching around and cannot find anywhere. so does anyone know if I can do this programatically or even add formatting to the docX document?

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 1):

I worked this out and thought I should share in case someone else finds it useful.

In the docX document you can add formatting options in the MergeField. 
Right click on the field you want to format and select 'Toggle Field Codes', This will change the MergeField to look something like:

```
{MERGEFIELD NetGoodsAmount \* MERGEFORMAT}
```

Replace the '\*' with your format options. So if you want negative numbers in brackets change it to:

```
{MERGEFIELD NetGoodsAmount \#"#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)"\* MERGEFORMAT}
```

I couldn't find any GUI in words that refers to these options so it looks like you have to do this manually.

Hope that helps someone,
Ryan M